# Can't update the values in database

Tags: java, android

I want to update the values in the database and launch it using a button

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(); 
        cv.put("word",word); 
        cv.put("definition", def); 
        database.rawQuery("update priv_dbms set word ='"+word+"',
                              definition='"+def+"'", null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Successfully Updated!!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Priv_DBMS.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

When I launch the application, there are no errors, but the values are not updated in the database.

This is my code to get values from edit text:

```
passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra(WordExtend_priv_dbms.ID_EXTRA2);
passedView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editword);
passedView.setText(passedVar);
passedVar1=getIntent().getStringExtra(WordExtend_priv_dbms.ID_EXTRA1);
passedView1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdef);
passedView1.setText(passedVar1)
word = passedView.getText().toString();
def = passedView1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: How are you getting the database object? and from where?

Comment: I already got it codes to get the strings in edittext is being missplaced

Answer (score 1):

Try this in onclick ::

```
String query = "update priv_dbms set word =\""+word+"\", definition=\""+def+"\"";

SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL(query);

db.close();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Successfully Updated!!",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Priv_DBMS.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put this in `onClick`

```
String word = passedView.getText().toString();
String def = passedView1.getText().toString();
```

Where `passedView` and `passedView1` is from here

```
passedView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editword);
passedView1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdef);
```

Thanks for the answers !!